# Flutter Images and Video Saved using path_provider not showing in Gallery

Tags: flutter

I want to record a video or audio in my Flutter App and wants it to appear in gallery. How can I do it because path_provider is saving file to safe location and one need a rooted device to access it.
I was trying [Flutter Camera Plugin Example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera#-example-tab-)

Also asked on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20807

Comment: I have opened a github issue regarding this problem at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20807#issuecomment-414226826

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Android? Photos you save to the device's external storage will appear in your gallery. If you want to do this in iOS, you will need to use the [flutter_photokit](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_photokit) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for help @KirollosMorkos right now I don't own an iOS Device so I am unable to test your suggestion. By the way, using Flutter plugin path_provider Function "getExternalStorageDirectory()" I am able to store the file in the external directory and they appear in the Gallery.

Comment: Yepp, that's the way to do it in Android!

Comment: any suggestion for Android? i am developing app with flutter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason I was facing the problem is that the example I was trying uses path_provider function "getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()" to store the files.
By replacing above Function with "getExternalStorageDirectory()" I am able to store the file in the external directory and they appear in the Gallery.

Comment: @GurleenSethi Sorry I use Windows laptop and have no idea about the ios. By the way, this library is pretty popular and I am sure there is a workaround for ios.

Comment: That's funny. As of 2020, I could never make images available in the Gallery using any directory that `path_provider` provides. I guest we need an updated recipe.

Comment: can we create a new folder in downloads folder?

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() not worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() not worked for me in iOS any other clue

Answer (score 0):

You need to do scan media files using broadcast intent.

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(YOUR_PATH)));
```